# No space left on device. This can happen if gsutil is configured to save tracker files to an unwritable directory)

Tags: google-cloud-storage

My end goal is to move large folders with many subfolders to a new GCS bucket with a different storage class.  Moving from standard to coldline.  I have tried doing this with the mv function, using rsync, and finally I was able to move objects using a GUI Mountain Duck and Expand Drive.  However once the items are moved to the new bucket they still retain the standard storage class.  I tried rewriting the storage class but I always get this error:

No space left on device. This can happen if gsutil is configured to save tracker files to an unwritable directory)

I get this same error when trying to rsync large files to the new bucket as well.  I am very new to GCS and don't really know what I am doing.  Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you're moving data within the same provider (not between, say, GCS and AWS), gsutil mv uses copy-in-the-cloud, so it shouldn't impact your local disk space. Can you try running the command using gsutil -d, save the output and edit out any details you don't want exposed (especially the Authentication headers, but you might also want to hide the bucket and object name) and posting that? That would let us see what operations are writing to the local disk.

Note also that copying to a new bucket will cause the object to have the default storage class of the new bucket, unless you specify the `-s` option on the `gsutil cp` command.

Also, if you just want to change the storage class of the objects you can do that without moving to a new bucket by using `gsutil rewrite -s`.

Comment: Thanks for commenting.  This is all very new to me and forgive me if I'm posting this incorrectly.  But for this example I tried to moved a large video file (4.34 GB) to a new storage class bucket and received the same error.  The output file is massive so it doesn't seem to want to let me post it here.  It's about 9,000 characters, is that normal?

Comment: I also tried to rewrite the storage class using the code you shared and I got this:
NOTE: No encryption_key was specified in the boto configuration file,
so gsutil will not provide an encryption key in its rewrite API
requests. This will decrypt the objects unless they are in buckets
with a default KMS key set, in which case the service will
automatically encrypt the rewritten objects with that key.

Comment: cont ...
CommandException: Couldn't write tracker file (/home/christian_simpson/.gsutil/tracker-files/rewrite_TRACKER_8262fa96de95b5b22ba076358c901bba47e96268..mov__JSON.token): No space left on device. This can happen if gsutil is configured to save tracker files to an unwritable directory)

Comment: This same error over and over again not matter what I try.  And it's only for larger files sizes.

Comment: Is there something that automatically blocks files of certain sizes to be moved around within my GCS account?  Do I need to change any size in the Computer Engine?

Comment: That tracer file error is your basic problem: you ran out of space and can't write to that file (it's just a modest amount of metadata, not the actual file you're trying to move). Try running:

df -h /home/christian_simpson/.gsutil

You'll see the device is full.

You can either clear up some space on that device or change the gsutil configuration to put tracker files on another device. You can do this by adding a resumable_tracker_dir=<path> under the "[GSUtil]" section of your .boto config file.

Comment: I did run that and you're right, I have 4.8 GB available and I've used 4.6.  Forgive me but I am totally ignorant to what this even is and what the .boto config file is.  My end goal is just to be able to move any size file around in GCS to do different buckets with different storage classes.  
When you say change gsuitl configuration to put trakcer files on another device I don't know who or where these devices are?  Forgive my complete ignorance.  Your help is immensely appreciated.

Comment: If you run:

df

it will show all the devices you have mounted and the file system mount points for each. By default gsutil stores tracker files under your home directory. You can see which device it's on by doing:

df ~

You need to pick a different file system from those in the first 'df' listing, that has more space; or you need to free up some space in your home directory.